# Sharepoint Column Format - How to handle blank dates with JSON Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am quite new to JSON Column formatting for Sharepoint.

I have entered in the following code, however, I am not sure how to add in the blank condition. Basically all applications that are more than 15 days past the date entered into the Date Sent to Assessor Column. The issue is that when there is no date, the value is still formatting as overdue, therefore I want to add in the blank condition.

This is the current code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": ">=",
          "operands": [
            "[$Is_x0020_Assessor_x0020_Report_x]",
            15
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgRed sp-css-color-BlackText sp-field-bold",
        {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Is_x0020_Assessor_x0020_Report_x]",
                0
              ]
            },
            "sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-GrayText",
            ""
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "[$Is_x0020_Assessor_x0020_Report_x.displayValue]"
}
```

This is what the current formatting looks like and as you can see, the blank column - the one displaying 44,889.915259444. I have tried referring to that number so that it won't format, but that doesn't work either.

[image: Current Formatting]

I do have a Date Sent to Assessor column as per the screenshot below and I actually wanted to put the same formatting on this column, however, the numbers just keep disappearing instead of having a red background and bold black text the same as the Assessor Report Overdue column.

[image: Date Column with Overdue Column]

May I ask for some help as to how I can enter in the blank condition? I thought this portion would handle the blank dates but it doesn't seem to work so I must have done something wrong.

```
"operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Is_x0020_Assessor_x0020_Report_x]",
                0
              ]
            },
            "sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-GrayText",
            ""
```

I have now tried the following JSON:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "=if(Number([$Date_x0020_Sent_x0020_to_x0020_Assessor_x0020_(QBuild,_x0020_Caravan,_x0020_Vessel)]) == 0, 'Assessment Not Sent', if([$Date_x0020_Sent_x0020_to_x0020_Assessor_x0020_(QBuild,_x0020_Caravan,_x0020_Vessel)] < @now, 'Overdue', 'Assessment with Assessor'))",
"attributes": {
    "class": "=if(Number([$Date_x0020_Sent_x0020_to_x0020_Assessor_x0020_(QBuild,_x0020_Caravan,_x0020_Vessel)]) == 0, 'sp-field-severity--warning', if([$Date_x0020_Sent_x0020_to_x0020_Assessor_x0020_(QBuild,_x0020_Caravan,_x0020_Vessel)] < @now, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', 'sp-field-severity--good'))"
}
```

}

And this is what the output looks like:

[image]

I also tried this version of the code - still no luck - it will only display the JSON but won't work:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "=if(Number([$Date_x0020_Sent_x0020_to_x0020_Assessor_x0020_(QBuild,_x0020_Caravan,_x0020_Vessel)]) == 0, 'Assessment Not Sent', if([$Date_x0020_Sent_x0020_to_x0020_Assessor_x0020_(QBuild,_x0020_Caravan,_x0020_Vessel)] < @now, 'Overdue', 'Assessment with Assessor'))",
"attributes": {
    "class": "=if(Number([$Date_x0020_Sent_x0020_to_x0020_Assessor_x0020_(QBuild,_x0020_Caravan,_x0020_Vessel)]) == 0, 'sp-field-severity--warning', if([$Date_x0020_Sent_x0020_to_x0020_Assessor_x0020_(QBuild,_x0020_Caravan,_x0020_Vessel)] <= @now + 15, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', 'sp-field-severity--good'))"
}
```

}

Comment: Check this, it should help you: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/

Comment: What is the data / column type of "Is Assessor Report Overdue" column?

Comment: Hello Ganesh, thank you so much for your help. The data column type is a calculated column and it is a number format. The column it calculates based on is the Date Sent to Assessor column which is a date only column.

Comment: Hello Ganesh, I have tried the following code but I am only getting the formula. I have updated the original post with the new code that I tried and the result.

Comment: I still need help with this if anyone out there is able to assist me please

Comment: Can you show us the calculated formula you have used for this column? It is better to check blank dates in calculated formula itself using ISBLANK() function and adapt your formula & outcomes accordingly.